# Cannot accurately asses Strings

Tags: java, string, equals

I wrote some code that is supposed to ask for input from the user and assign it to the String skillAssign. When I try to asses skillAssign, it returns false no matter what. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class CharacterCustomization
{
    public CharacterCustomization()
    {
    }
    public static void Customization()
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int skillPoints = 100;
        String skillAssign = "";
        int newMaxHealth = 0;
        int newMaxMagic = 0;
        int newMaxStamina = 0;
        int assignmentValue = 0;
        boolean isDone = false;
        System.out.println("Welcome to character customization, you have 100 points to allocate to your skills.");
        System.out.println("To allocate points, type name of skill, followed by the points you want to assign (blank for positive, - for negative, ex. -5)");
        System.out.println("Put Skill on one line, and press enter, then the value on the next line");
        System.out.println("Type \"stats\" to view full stats at any time");
        System.out.println("Type \"done\" to finish");
        while (true)
        {
            while (isDone == false)
            {
                skillAssign = keyboard.nextLine();

                if (skillPoints == 0)
                {
                System.out.println("Max Health: " + newMaxHealth);
                System.out.println("Max Magic: " + newMaxMagic);
                System.out.println("Max Stamina: " + newMaxStamina);
                System.out.println("Skill points left: " + skillPoints);
                System.out.println("Type \"done\"to finish");
            }
            if ((!(skillAssign.equals("stats"))) || (!(skillAssign.equals("done"))))
            {
                assignmentValue = keyboard.nextInt();
                if (((skillAssign.equals("health")) || (skillAssign.equals("Health"))) && (skillPoints - assignmentValue >=0))
                {
                    skillPoints = (skillPoints - assignmentValue);
                    newMaxHealth = (assignmentValue + newMaxHealth);
                }
                else if (((skillAssign.equals("magic")) || (skillAssign.equals("Magic"))) && (skillPoints - assignmentValue >=0))
                {
                    skillPoints = (skillPoints - assignmentValue);
                    newMaxMagic = (assignmentValue + newMaxMagic);
                }
                else if (((skillAssign.equals("stamina")) || (skillAssign.equals("Stamina"))) && (skillPoints - assignmentValue >=0))
                {
                    skillPoints = (skillPoints - assignmentValue);
                    newMaxStamina = (assignmentValue + newMaxStamina);
                }
                else
                {
                    //System.out.println("Sorry, I could not read that!");
                    System.out.println(skillAssign == "stats");
                }
            }
            else if (skillAssign.equals("stats"))
            {
                System.out.println("Max Health: " + newMaxHealth);
                System.out.println("Max Magic: " + newMaxMagic);
                System.out.println("Max Stamina: " + newMaxStamina);
                System.out.println("Skill points left: " + skillPoints);
            }
            else if ((skillAssign.equals("done")) || (skillAssign.equals("Done")))
            {
                isDone = true;
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Sorry, I could not read that!");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Are you sure this is the setup you want? [y] [n]");
        System.out.println("Max Health: " + newMaxHealth);
        System.out.println("Max Magic: " + newMaxMagic);
        System.out.println("Max Stamina: " + newMaxStamina);
        System.out.println("Skill points left: " + skillPoints);
        //skillAssign = keyboard.nextLine();
        if (((keyboard.nextLine()).equals("y")) || ((keyboard.nextLine()).equals("Y")) || ((keyboard.nextLine()).equals("yes")) || ((keyboard.nextLine()).equals("Yes")))
        {
            Player player = new Player(newMaxHealth, newMaxMagic, newMaxStamina);
        }
        else
        {
            isDone = false;
        }
    }
}
```

`}`

Its not complete, but Im inputting `stats` when prompted and all evaluations of it are false
Is there a way I can get it to read the variable properly?

Comment: Eevrywhere you used `equals()`, but just while printing you used `==`?

Comment: unrelated, but equalsIgnoreCase would reduce the number of IF conditions in your code.

Comment: Fixed that^, but when I input "stats" it still goes to the inside of
`if ((!(skillAssign.equals("stats"))) || (!(skillAssign.equals("done"))))`

Comment: **A.** You can use `"abc".equalsIgnoreCase("AbC")` instead what you're using now.
**B.** Don't add for every logical expression parenthesis it's making the code more complex and unclear for the first glance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will always get in inside this condition scope `if ((!(skillAssign.equals("stats"))) || (!(skillAssign.equals("done"))))`
It because that when one word failed to pass it, the other condition will let it pass, because they are different completely.
e.g:
let's take "stats", this will results with if (false || true) => true.
let's take "done", this will results with if (true || false) => true.
let's take "sTats", this will results with if (true || true) => true.

You can't escape it, you need to check it like that:
`if (!(skillAssign.equals("stats") || skillAssign.equals("done")))`
this way we're checking if either of the logical expression are true, then we change it to "not" and then checking if the whole condition is true.

**P.S**
A. You can use "abc".equalsIgnoreCase("AbC") instead what you're using now.
B. Don't add for every logical expression parenthesis it's making the code more complex and unclear for the first glance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was using `||` instead of `&&` in the `if ((!(skillAssign.equals("stats"))) || (!(skillAssign.equals("done"))))`

Answer (score 0):

What ever Orel said is pretty much it. Just wanna add if you are using `System.out.println(skillAssign == "stats")` to asses your skillAssign it will always return false, even if they have the same value.
Because `==` compare the reference of Strings not their values.
you must use `equals()` method.